# Scoping not working within ng-repeat

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a strange behaviour / bug within a ng-repeat in AngularDart:

If I use the following code I get no errors:

```dart
<div class="row col-xs-12" ng-repeat="step in tp2.plan.steps">
  {{ tp2.callback }}
  <travel-step step="step" deleteCallback="tp2.callback"></travel-step>
</div>
```

Callback is defined like this in my Controller:

```dart
@Controller(selector: '[add-travelplan-controller]', publishAs: 'tp2')
class AddTravelPlanController {

  Function callback = () {
    print("it works!");
  };
...
}
```

If I remove `{{ tp2.callback }}` I will get an error like:

```dart
No getter for 'callback'.
```

I'm using angular v. 0.12

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks should be passed like this :

```
<travel-step step="step" deleteCallback="tp2.callback()"></travel-step>
```

Remember to use @NgCallback in your component to do the binding, the you can call it from your component like this :

```
@NgCallback('deleteCallback')
Function deleteCallback;
delete(){
   deleteCallback();
}
```